# Open Cart decimal_point error on all price

Tags: opencart

I recent installed an OpenCart on server. I am facing an error `(decimal_point)` on all prices. Like up where cart shows `(0 item(s) - $0decimal_point00)` and bottom where product price is shown. I am new to OpenCart.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: I meant what all things you've tried to fix this issue!

Comment: just install. or nothing. i dont know where to fix this . i mean which file have to change. or check

Answer (score 2):

today I've solved this problem.

the

```
$_['decimal_point']= '.';
```

is displayed in 
catalog/language/language_name/language_name.php 
and 
admin/language/language_name/language_name.php

but you should copy this line to 
catalog/language/language_name/product/product.php

and everything will be ok

PS: language_name should be renamed to a correct name because at first I mistaken with french language pack and rename the folder to french but after I change it to frenc my store worked properly

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Add the line

```
$_['decimal_point']= '.';
```

in catalog/language/language_name/common/cart.php

Comment: You could add a little explanation to go with your answer so that it might help more people.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by updating language pack to latest version. It solve it completely.
So the reason is somewhere in language pack.

Answer (score 0):

I went into admin --> Home/Languages  and changed the directory value to match what was on the server in **a case sensitive way**.

On Windows it was working since it is case insensitive and Italian was with capital letter but when uploaded on Linux the case sensitiveness kicked in and this was shoung also strange timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I solved it in a very simple and silly way, after trying everything I found on each page about it.

I was showing "decimal_point" in the prices, because the language I configured it as **es-cr.php**, but the file in Spanish is called **es-es.php**, by not agreeing, I gave that error, so I just changed the name to **es-cr.php** and everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but if someone comes across it, the solution is to make sure you have the file [language_name]-[country].php in the following folders:

1. If the issue is in the admin side, the folder is: admin/language/[language_name]-[language_name] // ex.: for english, the folder is admin/language/en-gb, the filename is en-gb.php.
2. If the issue is in the store front, the folder is: catalog/language/[language_name]-[language_name] // ex.: for english, the folder is catalog/language/en-gb, the filename is en-gb.php.